# How to add margin/padding to flutterViewController inside viewController in IOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I added flutter to an existing Android and IOS project , it's done perfectly , but how to add top padding/margin to flutterView inside viewController in IOS project so the top navigation bar appear , because the flutterView cover the top navigation bar , here is the swift view controller code :

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

class FlutterView: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let flutterEngine = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.flutterEngine;
      let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)!;
      self.present(flutterViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

      flutterViewController.setInitialRoute("referral")

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
class FlutterView: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let flutterEngine = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.flutterEngine;
        let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)!;
//        self.present(flutterViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        addChild(flutterViewController)


        flutterViewController.setInitialRoute("referral")
    }


    func addChildViewControllerWithPadding(_ childController: UIViewController, padding: CGFloat) {
        addChild(childController)
        view.addSubview(childController.view)

        constraintsWithPaddingBetween(holderView: view, topView: childController.view, padding: padding)
        childController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func constraintsWithPaddingBetween(holderView: UIView, topView: UIView, padding: CGFloat) {
        guard holderView.contains(topView) else {
            return
        }
        topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                                        toItem: holderView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: padding)
        let pinBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,
                                           toItem: holderView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: padding)
        let pinLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: holderView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: padding)
        let pinRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: holderView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: padding)
        holderView.addConstraints([pinTop, pinBottom, pinLeft, pinRight])
    }

}
```

In the example above you will have padding within your current controller, but since you will add it as a child, this will automatically be part of your controller which I suppose is under the current navigation bar.

Maybe it is even better to create a dedicated subview in your controller.

Additionally I would recommend you to have the

`addChildViewControllerWithPadding` and `constraintsWithPaddingBetween`

as extensions on `UIViewController` and `UIView`.